# Can I prevent people from forking my code?

Tags: github

I want to know if there is a way to prevent your code from being forked. If the account is a free account it is obviously impossible to keep the stuff private, but is it at least possible to prevent people from forking the code? If there is a way I will appreciate instructions on how to do it.

Comment: You can prevent it from being forked by not making the code available. Anything else is going to either be ineffective, or at least not worth the hassle to enforce unless employing attorneys is worth the cost to you.

Comment: I am officially on bitbucket now. I have my code on there, and some of my Math and Physics stuff too. woohooo!!, free and private

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question

Comment: Update from 2021: github offers private repositories to everyone as well now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. According to the [GitHub Terms of Service](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/) (emphasis mine):

> Any User-Generated Content you post publicly, including issues, comments, and contributions to other Users' repositories, may be viewed by others. **By setting your repositories to be viewed publicly, you agree to allow others to view and "fork" your repositories** (this means that others may make their own copies of Content from your repositories in repositories they control).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, forking should be "by permission" and granted by the author. I have about sixty+ repositories which I have authored and countless people who:

1) fork my repository
2) commit absolutely nothing back to the community
3) pad their github account (pretending to be a busy coder?)
4) pin my forked repository in their highlights on their repository list
5) do no commits into their own fork of my code

Seriously, github should delete idle forked repositories. This is completely ridiculous. There are individuals with *hundreds* of forked repositories of others' code and they've offered nothing back to the community.

If you like the code, press the Star button so that it's on your list. If you have no intention of participating or writing code, stop forking it.

Note that a lot of these "code campers" are actually Github Pro users who can hide your code behind a private repository (taking but not giving back). Since you have no access to peek behind the curtain, you don't know if they've gone against your OSS license.

Comment: How would deleting forked repos help anyone? That just pushes the forks to remain hidden and private; it doesn't permit anyone from doing what Git was designed to do, and which you cannot prevent if you publish anything anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use private services like bitbucket for free or under a paid account in Github.

By default all the unpaid repositories in github are free, and as a result are forkable.